# Is there a way to print numbers like this with for loop

Tags: python, loops, input

I want to write a code that can output a result like this:

```
123456
 23456
  3456
   456
```

and about how many layers I want to have, I need to use the input method ,
but I cannot get the result I want.

I have tried this :

```
layers = int(input('layers: '))

for i in range(1,layers+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print('123456',end ="")
    print('')
```

I cannot figure out where I am doing wrong, the output is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem this way :

```
layers = int(input("layers: "))

for i in range(1,layers+1):
   numbers = "".join([str(j) for j in range(i,layers+1)])
   print(" "*(layers-len(numbers)) + numbers)
```

Output:

```
123456
 23456
  3456
   456
    56
     6
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help but it is js. However you can use this algorithm to meet your goal.

```js
let level = 5;

let str= "";

for (j=1; j<=level; j++){
  for (k=1; k<=j; k++){//increase space
    str = str + " ";
  }
  for (i=j;i<=level;i++) {//decrease text
    str = str + i;
  }
  console.log(str);
  str = ""; //reset text
}
```

Comment: Ohh Nooo.. Python ONLY SOrrY

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the `.replace()` function:

```
layers = int(input('layers: '))

for i in range(1,layers+1):
    a = '123456'
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        a = a.replace(str(j-1)," ")
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can iterate backwards in `range`

```
layers = int(input('layers: '))

for i in range(layers,0,-1):
    print(' '*(layers-i),end='')
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j,end ="")
    print('')
```